# Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory pandas python, large file csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, memory, large-files

I have a large csv file of 3.5 go and I want to read it using pandas.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
tp = pd.read_csv('train_2011_2012_2013.csv', sep=';', iterator=True, chunksize=20000000, low_memory = False)
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

I get this error:

```
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:8771)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9731)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:9602)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:23325)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of
```

The capacity of my ram is 8 Go.

Comment: what about just `pd.read_csv('train_2011_2012_2013.csv', sep=';')` ?

Comment: In addition to any other suggestions, you should also specify `dtypes`.

Comment: @Boud my computer don't support it

Comment: Noobie's answer above is using even more memory because you are loading a chunk and appending it to mylist (creating a second copy of the data). You should read in a chunk , process it, store the result , then continue reading next chunk. Also , setting dtype for columns will reduce memory.

Answer (score 25):

try this bro:

```
mylist = []

for chunk in  pd.read_csv('train_2011_2012_2013.csv', sep=';', chunksize=20000):
    mylist.append(chunk)

big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)
del mylist
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but there an error in big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis=0)                                                                                                         out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype, order='F')
    929         else:
--> 930             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
    931 
    932     func = _get_take_nd_function(arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis,

MemoryError:

Comment: Loaded 3G CVS successfully! Thanks!

Comment: Just came across this. Perfect!

Comment: I am reading two big csv files one after another. This is not working. Any suggestions please? My csv size is 980 MB

Comment: This worked for me. I had a CSV file with a size of 13.2 GB.

Answer (score 4):

This error could also be caused by the **chunksize=20000000**. Decreasing that fixed the issue in my case.
In ℕʘʘḆḽḘ's solution chunksize is also decreased which might have done the trick.

Comment: If it is already answered in ℕʘʘḆḽḘ's solution then just comment this. No need to put it as an answer.

Comment: I wanted to do that but didn't have enough reputation. Just wanted to leave this info for future reference, I haven't found it when I was googling for this error

Answer (score 2):

You may try setting *error_bad_lines = False* when calling the csv file i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_big_file.csv', error_bad_lines = False)
```

Comment: Pandas version: `1.3.4` :`FutureWarning: The error_bad_lines argument has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add parameter `engine='python`. It loads the data slower but it helped in my situation.